# Listivew layout wont work without @android:id/text1

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="miki"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/ivUserIcon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/key" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why doesnt this code work? app crashes with it.

The only way the app does not crash is like this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="3dip"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="miki"
android:textSize="30dp"
android:gravity="center" />
```

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening? how can i add stuff to it, not only just TextView

Comment: you haven't closed the RelativeLayout

Comment: @albertoqa edited, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom adapter, as the ListView by default only supports views with a TextView as the root element (opening XML tag).

Here's a good place to look:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample

Comment: on that link, they use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 like i do, which only works (unless i make custom xml with @android:id/text1, basically copying simple_list_item_1), so how could i fix that?